# jquery draggable set containment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a draggable div to which I want to set containment 80% of parent. How can I achieve this ?

```
$( ".content-columns-sep" ).draggable({
            axis: "x",
            containment: "parent",
            cursor: "crosshair",
            grid: [10, 0],
            drag: function(event, ui) {
                ..
            }
        });
```

Comment: 80% width, height, internal area...? work with us here.

Comment: Ever considered making a div occupy 80% of its parent and making a draggable work 100% in that div?

Comment: @Neil - That was exactly what I was thinking as well...

Comment: I had considered it @Neil but then just wondering if there's any easy way to do it in jquery (since I'm quite new to it). Guess I'll take your suggestion

Comment: @Rohan, I seriously doubt you can do this in jQuery without a bit of tweaking.  I think the reason for which is precisely this, that you could create a div to just about represent any space on a web page which you'd want to make draggable, hence such an enhancement would probably go to waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Neil suggested, you can use an internal div that is 80% of its parents size, and then constraint dragging to within that div. Here is a quick-and-dirty [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgMWv/).

For reference, the markup is:

```
<div style="background-color: grey" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <div class="internal-area">
      <p style="background-color: red" id="draggable5" class="ui-widget-header">
        I'm contained within a percentage of my parent
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The styles are:

```
.draggable { width: 300px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
.internal-area { width: 80%; height: 80%; background-color: white; margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 30px;}
#draggable, #draggable2 { margin-bottom:20px; }
#draggable { cursor: n-resize; }
#draggable5 { cursor: e-resize; width: 70px;}
#containment-wrapper { width: 90%; height:150px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; }
```

And the code is:

```
$( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

Comment: I am new to jquery so I was wondering if there was any other way to do this which is easier. I think I will go with your answer for now. Thankyou